# Netbeans Login form

Tags: java, database, forms, netbeans, authentication

I am having a problem with login form in java it seems there is nothing wrong with the connection to the database but still when i clicked the login button nothing is happening my guess is there is something missing or error in my code but i can seem to find it I hope you guys help me Thanks in advance :)

```
package splash_screen;


import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Loginform extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
public Loginform() {
    initComponents();
    conn=Connect.connectDB();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated     Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Username:");

    jLabel2.setText("Password:");

    jButton1.setText("Login");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
                 .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addContainerGap(197, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(197, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                         
    String sql="Select * from Account where username=? and password=?";

        try{
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,jTextField1.getText());
            pst.setString(2,jPasswordField1.getText());

            rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);

            if(rs.next()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password and Username is correct");
                Home a=new Home();
            a.setVisible(true);

            }
            else{
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password and Username is incorrect"); 
            }

        }
        catch(SQLException e){

        }
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loginform.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loginform.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loginform.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loginform.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Loginform().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Start by replacing the empty catch block, which hides any SQLException you might get, by `throw new RuntimeException(e);`. You think nothing happens because you probably get an exception, but deliberately choose to catch it and ignore it completely. So you shoot yourself in the foot because now you don't have any idea anymore of what could be wrong.

Comment: add **e.printStackTrace()** in catch block. then you will notice your error..

Comment: @JBNizet sorry but don't be mean about it I am just askin' geez so harsh :|

Comment: I'm not being mean, I'm just explaining why catching exceptions and ignoring them is not a good idea at all. Why don't you do what I'm suggesting and tell us what happens, instead of complaining?

Comment: @JBNizet here's what happen "java.sql.SQLException: not supported Prepared Statement

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
rs.executeQuery(sql);
```

by

```
rs.executeQuery();
```

The SQL string has already been passed to the statement at construction time.